# stdio to terminal after close(STDOUT_FILENO) behavior

Tags: c, linux, buffer, stdio

I am wondering why uncommenting that first printf statement in the following program changes its subsequent behavior:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  //printf("hi from C \n");

  // Close underlying file descriptor:
  close(STDOUT_FILENO);

  if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Direct write\n", 13) != 13) // immediate error detected.
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on write after close(STDOUT_FILENO): %s\n", strerror(errno));

  // printf() calls continue fine, ferror(stdout) = 0 (but no write to terminal):
  int rtn;
  if ((rtn = printf("printf after close(STDOUT_FILENO)\n")) < 0 || ferror(stdout)) 
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on printf after close(STDOUT_FILENO)\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "printf returned %d\n", rtn);
  // Only on fflush is error detected:
  if (fflush(stdout) || ferror(stdout))
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on fflush(stdout): %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Without that first printf, the subsequent printf rtns 34 as if no error occured even though the connection from the stdout user buffer to the underlying fd has been closed. Only on a manual fflush(stdout) does the error get reported back.
But with that first printf turned on, the next printf reports errors as I would expect.
Of course nothing is written to the terminal(by printf) after the STDOUT_FILENO fd has been closed in either case.

I know it's silly to `close(STDOUT_FILENO)` in the first place here; this is an experiment I stumbled into and thinking someone more knowledgeable in these areas may see something instructive to us in it..

I am on Linux with gcc.

Comment: `stdout` is in a bad state as you closed the underlying descriptor `STDOUT_FILENO` things work correctly with `fclose(stdout)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `strace` the both programs, it seems that `stdio` works so that upon *first* write, it checks the descriptor with `fstat` to find out what kind of file is connected to the `stdout` - if it is a terminal, then `stdout` shall be *line-buffered*, if it is something else, then `stdout` will be made block-buffered. If you call `close(1);` before the first `printf`, now the initial `fstat` will return `EBADF` and as `1` is not a file descriptor that points to a character device, `stdout` is made block-buffered.

On my computer the buffer size is 8192 bytes - that many bytes can be buffered to be written to `stdout` *before* the first failure would occur.

---

If you uncomment the first `printf`, the `fstat(1, ...)` *succeeds* and Glibc detects that `stdout` is connected to a terminal; `stdout` is set to line-buffered, and thus because `printf after close(STDOUT_FILENO)\n` ends with newline, the buffer will be flushed right away - which will result in an immediate error.

Comment: What is strange is that printing 1024 characters then leads to state change... Looping over the printf can easily exhibit this.

Comment: Yes, this internal setting up of the buffer via `fstat` call that you described, seems consistent with what `man setbuf` says: "The setvbuf() function may be used only after opening a stream and before any other operations have been performed on it." If I replace that first `printf` with `setlinebuf(stdout);` it behaves the same.

Comment: So an analagous caveat seems to apply to `printf` as the one appearing in the Notes within `man 2 write`:  "A  successful return from write() does not make any guarantee that data has been committed to disk." replacing 'write()' with 'printf()' and 'disk' with 'kernel file buffer'. Here `fflush` and `fsync` would be analogues. I don't know of an analogue to `close(fd)` that would sever the connection from the kernel file buffer to the disk..

Comment: After understanding the internals of how this is working, it seems to me that stdio library should report an error when it first discovers that the underlying fd is bad. So when the initial call to `fstat` returns `EBADF`, i think `printf` should return -1, rather than just setting the stdio buffer to block-buffered as if it was writing to a disk file.